# `\cs_set_eq:NN` doesn't work for `\frac`

Tags: expl3

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN \__examzh_symbols_old_frac:nn \frac
\RenewDocumentCommand { \frac } { m m }
  {
    \__examzh_symbols_old_frac:nn {#1}{#2}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

$\frac{1}{2}$

\end{document}
```

I wanted to redefine the `\frac` for "improvement". But I found that when I wanted to "copy" a `\frac` by `\cs_set_eq:NN`, it seemed that `\cs_set_eq:NN` failed and I didn't know why.

[image: MWE]

Then I used `\NewCommandCopy` and it worked:

```latex
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% \cs_set_eq:NN \__examzh_symbols_old_frac:nn \frac
\NewCommandCopy { \oldfrac } { \frac }
\RenewDocumentCommand { \frac } { m m }
  {
    % \__examzh_symbols_old_frac:nn {#1}{#2}
    \oldfrac {#1}{#2}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

$\frac{1}{2}$

\end{document}
```

Could you tell me what's wrong with the method of `\cs_set_eq:NN`?

[image]

Comment: `\frac` is a robust command, that means it has an specific internal structure. A simple \let (or \cs_set_eq:NN) can't properly copy this structure. That's why `\NewDocumentCopy` exists.

Comment: Or rather, `\NewCommandCopy`. :-) FWIW, `letltxmacro` would also work here, AFAIK.

Comment: Thanks for much! @Ulrike Fischer and frougon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```tex
% ltmath.dtx
\DeclareRobustCommand\frac[2]{{\begingroup#1\endgroup\over#2}}
```

will define two, not one, new macros: `\frac` and `\frac␣`.

```tex
\def\frac{\protect\frac␣}
\long\def\frac␣#1#2{{\begingroup #1\endgroup \over #2}}
```

This way, `\frac` is automatically protected, hence in LaTeX2e's term, robust. See also [What is the difference between Fragile and Robust commands? When and why do we need \protect?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4736).

Thus you need some "deep" copy commands compared to shallow copy ones.

- deep copy: `\NewCommandCopy` since LaTeX2e 2020-10-01 or `\LetLtxMacro` from `letltxmacro` package.
- shallow copy: primitive `\let` or the l3 function `\cs_set_eq:NN`

  ```tex
  \cs_new_protected:Npn \cs_set_eq:NN #1 { \tex_let:D #1 =~ }
  ```

Comment: Thanks so much!